# Approximating the conditional expectation E(X|Y)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, probability

I'm trying to find a way to approximate the conditional expectation E(X|Y) in python.
All I have are two lists of numbers, X and Y and I don't have any other knowledge about them.

Is there a good method for doing so?
I tried using all kind of smoother functions but the result was not good at all.

For example,
X = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, ....] and Y = [1, -1, 1, -1, ...] I would expect that E(X|Y) = 1 because X is constant regardless of Y.

Comment: Can you show some example code with concrete inputs and what you expect as result?

Comment: Just to confirm, do 1 and -1 correspond to True and False respectively? Because to me, that is the only thing that makes sense. `E(X|Y)` means `E(X)` given that `Y` has occurred/is true. `E(X|Y)` with a whole distribution of numbers just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the future, it's a good idea to post statistics questions on the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or the [data science site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree with @shadowtalker that this really belongs in a statistics site. But I gave an answer anyhow, though it does require a big third part dependency it is a package that allows you to do what you want. I gave an example with code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is actually very broad, and thus the are many answers to your question as asked. Taking a broad view of the term machine learning, this is a question that people have been trying to answer in machine learning for a very long time. The answer really depends on the assumptions that you make about the distribution of X|Y and the relationship between X and Y.

I will suggest the sci-kit learn package because it gives a number of ways to calculate E(X|Y). Lets start with your example and use simple linear regression (this makes the assumption that the relationship between X and Y is linear)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = np.ones((100,1))
Y = np.ones((100,1))
Y[0:-1:2] = -1
LR = LinearRegression()
LR.fit(Y,X)
a = LR.coef_
b = LR.intercept_
```

Now in this case since we assumed a linear relationship E(X|Y) = aY + b and in the example above the linear regression tells us that a = 0 and b = 1. This gives you the conditional expectation that you expect (all expectation values equal to 1 regardless of the value of Y).

As I mentioned though there are many many ways of trying to estimate E(X|Y), for instance k-nearest neighbors can be used (and is implemented in sklearn) or Gaussian  Process Regression (GPR) both of which do not require the assumption of a linear relationship between variables (the work very differently of course, where GPR requires a kernel function which we know from Mercer's theorem allows us to pick varying levels of smoothness for the function that is fitted to the data, whereas k-nearest neighbors estimates E(X|Y) at every point by averaging over its k-nearest neighbors as measured by some distance function). And there are many many more examples which you could explore in this wonderful package. It is a very interesting field!

Edit: Now I will add some example code for KNN and Gaussian Process Regression

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

X = np.ones(100)
Y = np.ones(100)

Y[0:-1:2] = -1
X = X.reshape(1,-1)
Y = Y.reshape(1,-1)

neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)

neigh.fit(Y, X)
print(neigh.predict(Y))
```

This returns all ones, again as expected. Note that in the case of KNN E(X|Y) = Ave(neighbors(X)) and thus does not need to be linear (or even smooth for that matter).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel

X = np.ones(100)
Y = np.ones(100)

Y[0:-1:2] = -1
X = X.reshape(1,-1)
Y = Y.reshape(1,-1)

kernel = DotProduct() + WhiteKernel()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel).fit(Y,X)

print(gpr.predict(Y))
```

The above example was for Gaussian process regression and it results in an array of numbers that is very close to (but not exactly) 1 as expected. Note here that the relationship between the variables is assumed to have some level of smoothness depending on the kernel. In this case a constant kernel should have worked fine, but I figured we could have an example where of how to choose the kernel built in.

Comment: Hi, I know the question was very broad but it was hard for me to explain the problem the way you did which was perfect. Thank you for the answer! if it is possible, can you elaborate a bit more about using K-nearest neighbors or GPR. I'm just entering this field and it is really an interesting field.

Comment: @Euler Sure, I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions here:

- 1 corresponds to True, -1 corresponds to False
- `X` and `Y` are the same length and are independent
- `X` and `Y` are stored in lists

Here's a review of Bayesian statistics (I don't know how to write equations here, sorry):

```
P(X) = probability of X being True = (# of True elements in X) / (# of elements in X)

P(Y) = probability of Y being True = (# of True elements in Y) / (# of elements in Y)

P(X and Y) = probability of both X and Y being True = P(X) * P(Y)

P(X given Y) = P(X | Y) = probability of X being True given that Y is True = P(X and Y) / P(Y)
```

And here's how to implement that into code:

```
X = np.array(X, dtype=int)
Y = np.array(Y, dtype=int)

p_X = len(np.where(X == 1)[0]) / len(X)
p_Y = len(np.where(Y == 1)[0]) / len(Y)

p_X_and_Y = p_X * p_Y
p_X_given_Y = p_X_and_Y / p_Y
```

This gives the correct answer of `p_X_given_Y = 1`.